# python loop through imports & check for variable

Tags: python, import, for-loop, dir

I've successfully imported a bunch of modules in a folder using

```
from assets import *
```

Now i want to loop through those imported modules and check for a specific variable or function. I tried to use dir() function to get a list of imported modules and look through them, but because i'm looping through an array of strings, instead of an array of modules technically, i can't lookup the module var.

```
for aModule in dir(assets):
    if word in aModule.alt:
        print "found it!"
```

> if word in aModule.alt:
>
> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'alt'

Comment: i found the solution here http://loquehumaine.wordpress.com/2011/04/05/python-packages-modules-how-to-loop-through-all-subpackages/. Gott use sys.modules["assets."+item].alt

Answer (score 3):

I think what you're doing could be done much more simply:

```
import assets
for aModule in vars(assets).values():
    if hasattr(aModule, 'alt') and word in aModule.alt:
        print "found it!"
        print aModule.__name__
```